# Efficiency when adding values from two lists

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm trying to learn algorithms by writing a python application that tests out Fermat's last theorem. It iterates all combinations of a^n + b^n = c^n Where a/b hit a ceiling at 10000 and n hits a ceiling at 100. I realize I won't get any hits, but it's just a bit of fun. Anyway, the specifics don't really matter.

What it boils down to is a + b where a and b iterate all combinations 1 to 10000. But here's the problem: 4 + 5 is exactly the same as 5 + 4. So my program is doing twice the work it needs to do. How can I iterate these combinations while skipping over mirrored inputs?

```
base_ceiling = 10000 # max values for a and b
n_ceiling = 100 # max value for power of n

powers = []
for i in range(n_ceiling):
  jarr = []
  for j in range(base_ceiling):
    jarr.append(j ** i)
  powers.append(jarr)

for k in range(3, n_ceiling):
  for i in range(1, base_ceiling):
    for j in range(1, base_ceiling):
      pow_vals = powers[k]
      a = powers[k][i]
      b = powers[k][j]
      c = a + b
      try:
        idx = pow_vals.index(c)
        if idx > -1:
          print k, ": ", i, j, "=", idx, " results in ", a, b, "=", c
      except ValueError:
        continue
```

Comment: Change the innermost loop to be `for j in range(i, base_ceiling)`, so that `i` is always less than or equal to `j`, never greater than.  You'd still duplicate some work whenever `i` equals `j`, but that's a negligible portion of the overall work.

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as using `for j in range(i, base_ceiling)`. This works because it will start from `i` instead of `1`, so it doesn't repeat anything less than `i`. You could use `i + 1` instead, because `i^n + i^n` will never be a power of `n`.